# Cognito User Pool and Wordpress Users (signing in to wordpress with AWS)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

There are applications that uses Amazon Web Services and AWS User Pool for the user registry. I would like to be able to signed-in to the Wordpress cms site using the AWS app's users / AWS User Pool login info.

Has anyone done something like this?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

You can manage such an integration by using the AWS SDK for PHP and writing a wordpress plugin that hooks into the authenticate call as described in the tutorial below:

https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/7175/wordpress-replace-built-in-user-authentication

Instructions for installing the AWS SDK for PHP into your plugin can be found here (I followed the composer instructions to get it working):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html

After that, a piece of code that deals just with User Pools authentication would be:

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Aws\CognitoIdentityProvider\CognitoIdentityProviderClient;
    $cognitoIdentityProviderClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(['version' => '2016-04-18',
        'region'      => 'us-east-1',
        'credentials' => array(
            'key'    => get_option('aws_access_key_id'),
            'secret' => get_option('aws_secret_access_key')
        )]
    );

    $authResult = $cognitoIdentityProviderClient->adminInitiateAuth([
        'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
        'UserPoolId' => get_option('cognito_userpoolid'),
        'ClientId' => get_option('cognito_clientid'),
        'AuthParameters' => ['USERNAME' => $username, 'PASSWORD' => $password],
    ]);
```

This is an authenticated call so it requires AWS credentials as you can see in my code above for the placeholders aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key. Here is a link to AWS documentation for managing credentials in PHP:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html

Comment: Thanks so much! I do have few questions: (1) On the site (https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/7175/wordpress-replace-built-in-user-authentication) for writing the wordpress plugin, there is a 'auth_serv.php ' file that needs to be created, but those usernames & passwords are hard-coded, will I need to replace those code with something else? (2) Where should the function code "function demo_auth(..){...}" be placed? in a separate php file? (3) Thanks again for the code above, where should the piece of code that deals just with User Pools authentication be placed? same as the function code file?

Comment: The username and password are not hard coded. They come from the Wordpress system since this is a Wordpress plugin, you are just adding a hook to call your method instead of the built-in Worpdess authentication that uses the Wordpress database. add_filter( 'authenticate', 'demo_auth', 10, 3 ); Most of it is explained here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268665/set-up-wp-authentication-from-external-api

Comment: Thanks! When I look  at the code from the link you provided (https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/7175/wordpress-replace-built-in-user-authentication) `if($_GET['user'] == 'bob' && $_GET['pass'] == 'asdf') {
    echo json_encode(array('result' => '1', 'username' => 'bob', 'first_name' => 'Bob', 'last_name' => 'Jacobsen', 'email' => 'aaben@lobaugh.net'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('result' => '0'));
}` It added bob as the username to the wp site. Do I replace that code in auth_serv.php with your piece of code that deals just with User Pools authentication? Thanks again!

Comment: That would be the jist of it. But I would suggest reading up on writing Wordpress plugins a little more since Wordpress relies heavily on the internal Wordpress database so there needs to be a sync between the users you have in the internal Wordpress database and the users that come from your external authentication provider.

Comment: Great response! This has helped me a ton as well!